# How to initiate a deliverSM to the SMSC simulator (smpp server) Java smscsim OpenSMPP 2.0

Tags: java, smpp

Could someone assist please. I'm currently using OpenSMPP 2.0 to build an SMPP Server. So, I'm Testing the SMPP Server with a SMPP Client on Transceiver mode. I can Send SMS successfuly from a client. But I cannot receive. My questions is How to initiate a deliverSM from somewhere to the SMPP Server then my SMPP Client will receive it ?

To be more clear, I need to know How to test a Receiver SMPP Client with OpenSMPP 2.0.

Is someone help and give me steps I can follow?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any success? I have similar problem.